# Eclipse Plugin to detect the activity of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am working on an Eclipse plugin project.
Which extension point should I use to detect the activity of Eclipse. Like, when it is minimized or not on the top level of screen, plugin stops to counting.
Right now, I can just use “org.eclipse.ui.startup“ extension point, and my plugin starts to count when Eclipse starts and keep counting until it is closed which is not good.
Please help me with some advice!!!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `ShellListener` on the `Shell` for the workbench window:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

Shell shell = window.getShell();

shell.addShellListener(listener);
```

The shell listener is notified when the shell is activated, deactivated, closed, minimized (iconified) and restored (deiconified).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful. It tells me that I should work on shell. But could you please describe more about how to use shell in my plugin project. Can I use it in my startup function?